# How to simplify this spreadsheet formula?

Tags: date, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am working on my personal financial spreadsheet, and I have one table that lists columns like: "Month","Income",Expense","Notes", and I am building a 2nd table to use to build a new chart so I can view Year over Year comparisons to the data (ie, I will get all of the Januarys' data charted next to each other to compare).

Here is the formula I'm using to transpose this data, but I know there has to be a better way, but my searching is failing me:

```
=arrayformula({
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=1);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=2);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=3);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=4);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=5);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=6);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=7);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=8);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=9);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=10);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=11);
    filter(B5:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)=12)
})
```

This just seems so unwieldy, though it does what I want.  Any suggestions on how to simplify this a bit?

EDIT: for clarifications, I'm taking data that is like: `Jan 2015; Feb 2015; Mar 2015;` etc, and transposing it to: `Jan 2015; Jan 2016; Jan 2017; Feb 2015; Feb 2016; Feb 2017` etc.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({B5:B64,MONTH(A1:A24)},2,TRUE),COUNTA(B5:B64),1)
```

## Explanation

- `{B2:B64,MONTH(B5:B64)}` is a custom array of two columns, the input and a column of months.
- The `SORT` function sorts the custom array
- The `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` function removes the column of months.